# how to sort two groups A,B with "closestPair" action

Tags: sorting, data-structures

input : n nums not sorted

wnated output : n nums sorted

tools to solve problem :

if divide n nums to two gruops of numbers, A and B ( I can choosr how to divide it)
and I can use an action called " closest pair" that returns a number  x from A and a number y from B so that |x-y| is the minimal distance between nums in A and nums in B.
how can I sort any set of numbers with this?
thanks

Comment: Does your set include both positive and negative integers? Are the number of elements same in both the groups?

Comment: both positive and negetive.you have n elements to sort , but u can divide them into A and B however u wan to

Comment: Pls provide a sample input and output

Comment: added more info thanks